# How configure SimpleBrokerMessageHandler in SpringMessaging

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-messaging

I want to extend default behavior of DefaultSubscriptionRegistry. 
How can I configure SimpleBrokerMessageHandler to set custom SubscriptionRegistry
in XML?

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/inrightsApp">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/websocket/notify" allowed-origins="*"/>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/websocket/stomp/">

    </websocket:simple-broker>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the conf as follow

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/notify" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```